# onload scroll to a specific item in a scroll-able list

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to build a similar page like linkedin jobs. In linkedin jobs page (url:"https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/) first we've a grid job view
when a specific jobcard is clicked, we jump to another url:"https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=2429528234&pivotType=jymbii"

when we jump to the 2nd url we have a scrollable joblist view where the specific job card that was clicked is shown at the top.
I want to clone this exact system.specifically the scroll behavior.  If I click the 4th jobcard from page1, then I want to show the 4th jobcard at the top of the scrollable list in the 2ndpage just like linkedin do.
I figured out how to do the routing and layout but I'm having trouble figuring out the scroll behavior.
PLease help me figure it out, How can we do this?

Here is the job grid view where we click a specific card:
[image]
Please help me figure it out.

Here we get the specific item at the top of the scrollable job list:
[image]

Comment: Probably a combination of assigning React refs and scrolling elements into view. Have you a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried already?

Comment: No i havent coded it yet, just thinking how do do that.Yeah i think we've to use React refs and element.scrollintoview(aligntop) somthin like that. Having trouble on thinking how to select the clicked element